# Docker image with TAG

Tags: image, docker, tags

I am preparing the Azure AZ500 certification.
I am stuck on lab which consists to create with aTAG a local Docker image based on the loginServer.

The aim is to be able to push the VM image previously created locally to a private Azure repository.

```
PS C:\> az acr list
[
  {
    "adminUserEnabled": false,
    "creationDate": "2020-12-26T23:55:33.321068+00:00",
    "dataEndpointEnabled": false,
    "dataEndpointHostNames": [],
    "encryption": {
      "keyVaultProperties": null,
      "status": "disabled"
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/5a89d093-ada0-4d4e-9a12-fe7b87e94eff/resourceGroups/AZContainersRG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/AZDemoACRE",
    "identity": null,
    "location": "westeurope",
    "loginServer": "azdemoacre.azurecr.io",
    "name": "AZDemoACRE",
    "networkRuleSet": null,
    "policies": {
      "quarantinePolicy": {
        "status": "disabled"

PS C:\> docker images
REPOSITORY                                     TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front   v1          0e7801ad0561   12 hours ago   944MB
tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask                     python3.6   997d8bb5f569   8 days ago     944MB
mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis            6.0.8       3a54a920bb6c   2 months ago   103MB*

PS C:\> docker tag azure-vote-front azdemoacre.azurecr.io/azure-vote-front:v1
Error response from daemon: No such image: azure-vote-front:latest
```

Comment: You need to use the entire text in the "repository" and "tag" columns as part of the existing image name: `docker tag mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1 ...`.  This probably matches the name you gave `docker build -t`, and you can directly specify the destination registry there (possibly with multiple `-t` options).

Answer (score 0):

First verify if image exists,

```
docker image ls
```

If it is present then use it's image id to create a new tag,

```
docker tag <image_id> TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

for more details,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: Thanks guys, the path used was uncompleted.